# Change the column names after applying One Hot Encoding

Tags: python, pandas

I am using `OneHotEncoder` to create a matrix based on below dataframe.

```
CA    Mode       Avenue   
100   Cash       CC
101   Cheque     CC
103   Cash       DF
104   Digital    DF
```

So When I use `OneHotEncoder` the resultant dataframe should look like

```
CA     X0_Cash    x0_Cheque    X0_Digital   X1_CC    X1_DF
100      1           0              0          1       0
101      0           1              0          1       0
102      1           0              0          0       1
104      0           0              1          0       1
```

As we can see the column names have been changed. I want the column names as `Avenue_Cash`, `Avenue_Cheque` i.e. first the original column name followed by an 'underscore' and then row value.

How to achieve the same? Any clue?

Comment: Does using the `prefix=...` and `prefix_sep=...` help you? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `get_feature_names` method to set the column names as you'd like.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

# set up the data
X = [[100, "Cash", "CC"], [101, "Cheque", "CC"], [103, "Cash", "DF"], [104, "Digital", "DF"]]

# set up the OneHotEncoder with sparse=False
enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=False)

# fit the OneHotEncoder
enc.fit(X)

# define your column names
colnames = enc.get_feature_names(["CA", "Mode", "Avenue"])

# make your transformed dataframe
X_new =  pd.DataFrame(enc.fit_transform(X), columns = colnames)

X_new
   CA_100  CA_101  CA_103  ...  Mode_Digital  Avenue_CC  Avenue_DF
0     1.0     0.0     0.0  ...           0.0        1.0        0.0
1     0.0     1.0     0.0  ...           0.0        1.0        0.0
2     0.0     0.0     1.0  ...           0.0        0.0        1.0
3     0.0     0.0     0.0  ...           1.0        0.0        1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas.get_dummies which gives the result you want by default:

**Setup:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CA': {0: 100, 1: 101, 2: 103, 3: 104},
                 'Mode': {0: 'Cash', 1: 'Cheque', 2: 'Cash', 3: 'Digital'},
                 'Avenue': {0: 'CC', 1: 'CC', 2: 'DF', 3: 'DF'}})
```

**Solution:**

```
pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Mode', 'Avenue'])

    CA  Mode_Cash   Mode_Cheque Mode_Digital    Avenue_CC   Avenue_DF
0   100 1           0           0               1           0
1   101 0           1           0               1           0
2   103 1           0           0               0           1
3   104 0           0           1               0           1
```